# How do I create change the color of the arrow on hover over?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if I wrote my HTML correctly. The script I have might not run because of that. I use paragraph to create space between the arrow and the text above (not shown).

```
    <div class="littlebg">
<div class="text">
<hr>
Renowned Japanese author Haruki Murakami said he owns over <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/23/magazine/the-fierce-imagination-of-haruki-murakami.html?pagewanted=5&ref=baseball&_r=0">10,000 records</a>. He often references music in his stories, particularly the genres classical, jazz and American pop. His first job was at a record store, and he once ran a jazz bar, called the Peter Cat, in Tokyo with his wife.
 <a href="#begin2">
 <p><div class="arrow"></div></p>
<a href="#begin2">
  <p>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  </p>
</a>

<script>
    $("div.arrow").hover(function() {
        $('this').css("border", '#4da6ff');
    });
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and most browsers will attempt to fix it. The result is:

`<a href="#begin2">
    <p></p>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <p></p>
</a>`. However your jQuery would still work as it only targets the div, so are you getting any errors? Is your jQuery being run from within a document ready call or at the end of the page before the closing body tag?

Comment: paste the complete html

Comment: As @j08691 said your html is invalid but i think your problem you use 'this' in string format, try this $(this).css("border", '1px solid #4da6ff');

Comment: @j08691 How should I fix my HTML to make it valid?

Comment: The problem is that you wrap a div within a paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference is `$(this)` or `this`, not `$('this')`.

Also, you're only considering *mouseenter*, you should write the second callback when the mouse leaves the element and restore the previous value.

**Info**: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is slightly off, it should be:

```
$(".arrow").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #4da6ff");
});
```

But you can do this simply with CSS, without jQuery like this:

```
.arrow:hover {
  border: 1px solid #4da6ff;
}
```